# submit a form on page load with jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, submit, onload

I need to submit a form when the window is loaded with jQuery Mobile. This is my code, but it does not work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#form_id').submit();
});
```

I have tested with an alert function in the submit, but the alert does not work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#form_id').submit(function(){alert('wow');});
});
```

And the form :

```
<div data-role="page" id="default">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>My Title</h1>
    <a href="myLink" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse" class="ui-btn-left jqm-home">Accueil</a>
  </div><!-- /header -->
  <div data-role="content" >
    <form name="form_id" id="form_id" action="mylink" method="POST">
      <!--a simple input hidden inside-->                                                                                                      
    </form>
  </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /default -->
```

I use `jquery-1.6.4.min.js` and `jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js`

Tested on Chrome 16.0.912.77 m AND Firefox 9.0.1

Comment: Can I ask why you are submitting a form on page load?  Even if this worked, would it not cause some infinite loop of page loading -> submit -> page refresh/load... and so on...  (unless after post the user is redirected to another page).  If you just need some data passed to the server via POST, perhaps some AJAX via jQuery.post() would be a be a nicer / more effective solution.

Comment: do you want to go to another page on form loading?

Comment: This is how to make an online payment site. My action is directed to an external site, so I can not use ajax. Currently it works # 1, but not the mobile version. There is probably something that prevents me from detecting the loading of the window, then send my form.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try changing your form action attribute to some proper link like 'action.html' and try it. It will go to the new page

Comment: I can't change the action. For the moment, I have added a button submit, but I would like to know who to submit on load with jquery mobile. Thanks for interest!

Comment: what should happen on load? Load new content? What is the purpose of action 'mylink'?

Comment: MyLink is a link to an external site. On load, the form must be sent with data received by curl, and previously added in a comic.

Answer (score 0):

Did you doublecheck the actual ID of the form element on your page?  I have mine defined as "form1" in my code but when the page renders it's renamed to "aspnetform".  When I changed my jquery selector to find the correct ID it's fine.